# Docker hide files after mount volumes

Tags: docker

I have an application in PHP that has a container with the application and in it php and nginx. The problem is that when I mount the application, for example, the docker-compose

My docker-compose

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  db_data:
services:
    app:
        tty: true
        container_name: web-app
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
            args:
                PHP_VER: "8.0"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        expose:
            - "9000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/opt/web-crm/public_html

    db:
        container_name: web-db
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/db/Dockerfile
        environment:
            MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
            MARIADB_DATABASE: db-crm
            MARIADB_USER: db-crm
            MARIADB_PASSWORD: db-crm
        expose:
            - "3306"
        volumes:
          - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I want to mount files from the host to the container and now when I mount a lot of files disappear. When I make git stash, then all hidden files return back.

After running docker-compose, I run a script that runs composer install and that's it. I've never experienced files disappearing while mounting.

Any idea?

Comment: The volume mount completely hides everything in the image and replaces it with contents from the host.  (Not really specific to Docker, this is how Unix mounts in general work.)  If your application is installed into `/opt/web-crm/public_html` in your Dockerfile, I'd recommend against mounting a volume over that directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze Exactly, the application from the host is mounted in /opt/web-crm/public_html. So, how do I do it correctly so that everything works for me? Only that on my host I have a docker-compose.yml file in the application directory, and after mounting it disappears.

Comment: @DavidMaze If I understand well, I have 2 options: 1. I must copy app to container, and when I did some changes I must rebuild container? Second options is, store app in host with vendor directory and mount as volume? In this solution I must have php, nginx, composer on host machine and docker as a webserver. In my opinion, the second option excludes the use of docker, since I would have a webserver locally.